# Paginate al consultar API Woocomerce, Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, woocommerce

se puede paginar los resultados que recibo por la API de Woocomerce?? Se que los resultados de por si vienen con 10 registros por página, pero claro quiero por ejemplo crear la paginación de Laravel por 6 registros por página.

**Este es mi controlador**

```
public function verProductosCliente_user()

{
    if(auth()->user()->rol == 1){
        $cliente = User::find(Auth::User()->id);
            $woocommerce = new Client(
                $cliente->url,
                $cliente->consumerKey,
                $cliente->consumerSecret,
                [
                    'wp_api' => true,
                    'version' => 'wc/v3'
                ]
            );

        $productos = response()->json($woocommerce->get('products'));
        

        return view('ver-productos-tienda-cliente')->with(["cliente" => $cliente, "productos" => $productos]);
        
    }else{
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Se que se puede hacer esto `products?per_page=6` pero eso no activa el paginate de laravel y el `->paginate(6);` no funciona.

**Edición**
Estoy probando de varias formas incluso crear yo el paginador, pero siempre me encuentro el mismo problema, estoy haciendo esto:

En la vista debajo del foreach donde itero los productos:

```
<div class="clearfix">
   @for($i = 1; $i <= $numeroDePaginas; $i++)
     <a href="/?page={{$i}}">{{$i}}</a>
    @endfor
</div>
```

Luego en el controlador añado como dice el manual:

```
$numeroDePaginas = $productos->getHeader('X-WP-TotalPages')[0];
```

Pero ya utilize el paginate de laravel o esto ahora, siempre es el mismo error.

```
Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::getHeader does not exist.
```

Es por que el código esta en Json?? puedo cambiarlo, alguna sugerencia por favor!

**Nuevos avances**

Le estoy añadiendo esto al controlador:

```
$paginaActual = '';
if ($request->getRequestUri() === '/productos-ecommerce') {
   $paginaActual = 1;
   } else {
   $paginaActual = substr($request->getRequestUri(), 7);
   }

   $productos = $woocommerce->get('products?_embed&per_page=3&page=' .$paginaActual);
             
   $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
   $headers = $lastResponse->getHeaders();
   $numeroDePaginas = $headers['X-WP-TotalPages'][0];
```

Y así en la vista:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="miPagination">
    @for($i = 1; $i <= $numeroDePaginas; $i++)
        @if ($i == $paginaActual)
            <span class="active"> {{ $i }} </span>
        @else
            <a href="productos-ecommerce?page={{$i}}">{{$i}}</a>
        @endif  
    @endfor
</div>
```

Me carga la página pero cuando cambio de página me devuelve:

```
Error: Parámetro(s) no válido(s): page [rest_invalid_param]
```

Comment: probá con `$woocommerce->http->getRequest()->getHeaders()` o alguna variante de los ejemplos de [lastrequest/lastresponse](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php#response)

Comment: Hola he probado como me dices y si pongo `$numeroDePaginas = $woocommerce->http->getRequest()->getHeaders('X-WP-TotalPages')[0];` me devuelve `Undefined offset: 0` y si pruebo con la variable productos que creo que es la que toca `$numeroDePaginas = $productos->http->getRequest()->getHeaders('X-WP-TotalPages')[0];` me devuelve esto `Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::$http` @aloMalbarez

Comment: los headers de la conexión las va a tener quien hace la conexión en este caso es e `$woocommerce` que es una instancia de "cliente de woocommerce" y posee la property ( o función ) `getHeaders` ( dame los headers de la conexión que hiciste ), `$productos` parece ser de tipo `jsonresponse` y no posee esa propiedad ( o función ) para extraer los headers. Por otro lado fijate de tener bien el nombre de la función `getHeaders` con s sería diferente a `getHeader`  /1

Comment: Puede que un header venga repetido ( por eso se usa el `[0]` para tomar el primero, pq los subsiguientes pueden haber sido inyectados maliciosamente ) probá debugear con print_r o vardump ( en el enlace hay un ejemplo ) a ver qué es lo que viene en la response /2

Comment: Si el método o función que devuelve los/el header por nombre ya filtra para tomar el primero ( no retorna un array, retorna un valor ) es ahí que puede darte error usar el `[0]` /3

Comment: Hola @aloMalbarez al final encontre como sacar los headers y `X-WP-TotalPages` en mi pregunta, abajo he añadido nuevo código para que veas que sucede ahora, me devuelve error en los parametros, no se a que es debido. Un saludo

Comment: Ya encontre el fallo, ese número 7 no es correcto, tiene que ser 27 por los caracteres que tiene URI. Publico una respuesta, revisala si quieres. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Bien encontre la solución.

Hacemos esto en el controlador:

```
$paginaActual = '';
if ($request->getRequestUri() === '/productos-ecommerce') {
   $paginaActual = 1;
} else {
   $paginaActual = substr($request->getRequestUri(), 27);
}

 $productos = $woocommerce->get('products?_embed&per_page=8&page=' .$paginaActual);
             
 $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
 $headers = $lastResponse->getHeaders();
 $numeroDePaginas = $headers['X-WP-TotalPages'][0]
```

1)Creamos una variable vacia para poder con ella detectar en que página estamos, en lo que fallaba era que en el `->getRequestUri(), 27);` que ponia `7` en un principio, tenia que se 27 por el número de caracteres que tiene la URL.

```
$productos = $woocommerce->get('products?_embed&per_page=8&page=' .$paginaActual);
```

2)Luego aquí le decimos a la API de woocommerce que la página actual es la que sacamos por la variable.

3. Luego extraemos en una variable el `getResposnse'
4. Con esa variable extraemos los headers con `getHeaders`
5. y por último wordpress trae el total de páginas en `X-WP-TotalPages``

Y ya en la vista:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="miPagination">
    @for($i = 1; $i <= $numeroDePaginas; $i++)
        @if ($i == $paginaActual)
            <span class="active"> {{ $i }} </span>
        @else
            <a href="/productos-ecommerce/?page={{$i}}">{{$i}}</a>
        @endif  
    @endfor
</div>
```